# Restart LoopingCall task after error callback

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.internet

My LoopingCall task stops when it executes an errorcallback and I want to restart it.

My code looks something like this but I am not sure if I am doing it right or which would be the best way

```
from twisted.internet.task import LoopingCall
from twisted.internet import reactor

PROCESS_INTERVAL = 1

def periodic_task():
    print notDefined

def periodic_task_crashed(error):
    print "periodic task crashed"

lc = LoopingCall(periodic_task)
d = lc.start(PROCESS_INTERVAL)
d.addErrback(periodic_task_crashed)

reactor.run()
```

Then for now in my error callback I do this...

```
def periodic_task_crashed(reason):
    d = lc.start(PROCESS_INTERVAL)
    d.addErrback(periodic_task_crashed)
```

Is this the right way to do it? Could it enter in a recursive error loop?

Comment: "`...`" is a syntax error in Python, so I'm not sure what it is you're proposing here.  http://sscce.org

Comment: Ofc it's saying syntax error, Imagine it just prints something, my question is about how to restart the task inside def periodic_task_crashed(reason):

Comment: You may handle and report exceptions in periodic_task itself.

Comment: The example still doesn't run. Please provide a single example that exhibits the behavior that you don't expect.  Keep in mind that many of us answer LOTS of questions, so having each question in a format where we don't need to do a bunch of extra set-up work to combine various bits of code in the way we *hope* the asker intended us to combine them makes it much, much easier to answer.

Comment: I think it's a very simple and basic twisted code, anyway, just added the missing imports and voilà, you have a working example now, wasnt hard right? Now, if you run this, and it crash in the periodic_task I want to restart the periodic_task in the error callback